# Trigger Test Method stuck at 18% coverage

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

I've been working on this all night, so this post is my last resort.  I have a trigger that creates a Chatter post when an Opportunity is "Closed Won," giving details of the sale.

I thought I had everything correct in my Test, but it is only hitting 18% - code is below.

Thanks in advance!

**Opportunity Trigger:**

```
trigger ChatterWonOpportunity on Opportunity (after update) {

    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){

    if(o.IsWon == true && Trigger.oldMap.get(o.id).IsWon == false){

    String oppURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + o.id;

    String status = 'We just won ' + o.Name + 'for ' + '$' + o.Projected_Revenue__c + ' in revenue!';

    FeedItem post = new FeedItem();

        post.ParentId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        post.Title = o.Name;
        post.Body = status;
        post.LinkUrl = oppURL;
        post.Type = 'LinkPost';

    insert post;
    }
  }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
public class ChatterWonOpportunity_Test {
    static testMethod void insertFeedItem() {

        Opportunity oppToCreate = new Opportunity();
        oppToCreate.StageName = 'Introduction';
        oppToCreate.Name = 'Test';
        oppToCreate.CloseDate = date.today();
        oppToCreate.Amount = 350;
        oppToCreate.Projected_Revenue__c = 400;

        insert oppToCreate;

        oppToCreate.StageName = 'Won';

        update oppToCreate;

        String oppToCreateURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + oppToCreate.id;

        String status = 'We just won ' + oppToCreate.Name + 'for ' + '$' + oppToCreate.Projected_Revenue__c + ' in revenue!';

        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();

        post.ParentId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        post.Title = oppToCreate.Name;
        post.Body = status;
        post.LinkUrl = oppToCreateURL;
        post.Type = 'LinkPost';

        insert post;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you don't need the part after `update oppToCreate;` in your test method. the `update` statement will update the opportunity record in your test method which will execute the trigger. Can you please check your debug log as a result from running the test? Are there any errors or attempts to de-reference null objects? Also check if your 'Won' stage name is of type 'Closed/Won'.

Comment: Wow...yeah I had 'Won' instead of 'Closed Won'...now 100% coverage haha.  Thanks very much.  And I removed everything after oppToCreate - I was actually thinking about that since the test just needs to trigger the event - thanks for confirming!

Comment: I'll post this as an answer then :)

Comment: @McD: Just a FYI, You have a DML (inserting feeditem) in a for loop in the trigger, which is not the best practice. You should try to move it outside the for loop.

Comment: @theGreatDanton Thanks! How would I go about moving it outside the loop?

Comment: `list<feedItem> feedItemList = new list<feedItem>();

for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
 //somecode....
 
    FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        post.ParentId = UserInfo.getUserId();
  post...
  //add the feeditem  object in a list.
  
  feedItemList.add(post);
    }
//execute the DML statement outside the loop and this will be considered only one statement 
insert feedItemList;`

It may be little confusing to read the code in the comment, you may want to copy-paste in a codeeditor and check the code. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need the part after `update oppToCreate;` in your test method. The update statement will update the opportunity record in your test method which will execute the trigger.

There is something else wrong with your code, so please check the following:

1) Please check your debug log as a result from running the test. Are there any errors or attempts to de-reference null objects?

2) Check if your 'Won' stage name value is of type `Closed/Won` on the StageName field on the Opportunity object.